# Function to insert to text a random char

Tags: c#

I need to write a function which will find in a string limits `[insert - l] some text [/insert]` and put into each word a char specified in a limit (in example char l )
I think that I need to find all between [insert - l] [/insert] split it to array and put a char into each word in a random position, but my knowlogde isn't enough to write it. PLease help me=\

Example:

```
Musgrave was [insert - l] selected as a scientist-astronaut [/insert] by NASA in August 1967.
```

After function I have to get:

```
Musgrave was sellected als a scilentist-astrlonaut by NASA in August 1967.
```

Comment: Given: `___`; Expected: `____`.  Please fill in the blanks.

Comment: Please show us example data and desired result

Comment: This feels like a homework question (which is fine), but if it is, it's good to say so up front... the folks here will want to be sure to answer in a way that will help you learn, as opposed to just giving you some code.  Also, "put into each word a char specified in a limit" could mean several things.  Austin's suggestion to give example intput/output is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Only because I'm a glutton for punishment.  Here's my guess at what you were asking for.

```
var random = new Random();
string bigBlockOfText = @"blah blah [insert - l] some text [/insert] blah blah blah [insert - q] different text[/insert].";
var reg = new Regex(@"\[insert \- (?<char>.)\](?<text>.+?)\[/insert\]");
var matches = reg.Matches(bigBlockOfText);
for (int i = matches.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var match = matches[i];
    bigBlockOfText = bigBlockOfText.Remove(match.Index, match.Length);
    var replace = match.Groups["text"].Value;
    var insert = match.Groups["char"].Value;
    replace = replace.Insert(random.Next(replace.Length), insert);
    bigBlockOfText = bigBlockOfText.Insert(match.Index, replace);
}
```

Comment: Don't work =\ I need to put a char into each word between [insert - l][/insert] And this limits can repeat in text

Comment: It does work.  I tested it.  It just doesn't insert more than one character in each insert as your initial request didn't mention this.  Sorry, you get to do the rest.